# solution of absolute value equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

## Question: If $x + |x| + y = 7$ and $x + |y| - y = 6$, then $x + y =?$

### My solution:

I considered each cases of $x$ and $y$ i.e $x$ positive and $y$ positive, $x$ positive and $y$ negative, $x$ negative and $y$ positive, and finally $x$ negative and $y$ negative. After solving I found $x= 4$ and $y=-1$ is the solution. So, their sum is $4-1= 3$.

#### Is there any smarter way to solve this type of equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider one case:
If $y\ge0$ then $|y|=y$ , and
$$x+|y|-y=x=6$$
and
$$\underbrace{x+|x|}_{12}+y=7\implies y=-5$$
It is contradiction, hence $y<0.$ Similarly $x\le 0$ then $y=7$ whereas $x+\underbrace{|y|-y}_{0}=6$. So $x>0$ and $y<0$, we have
\begin{cases}
2x+y=7\\
x-2y=6
\end{cases}

Comment: Very clear answer!

Answer (score 2):

By inspection, $x+|x|$ vanishes for $x\le0$, immediately giving $y=6$, which is not compatible with the second equation. Similarly, $y\ge0$ gives $x=6$, not compatible with the first equation.

Then, $x\ge0,y\le0$ and

$$\begin{cases}2x + y = 7 \\x - 2y = 6.\end{cases}$$

Multiplying the first equation by $3$ and subtracting the second,

$$5(x+y)=15.$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $y=7-x-|x|$, giving an equation in a single unknown, $$x+|7-x-|x||-(7-x-|x|)=6.$$

Then for $x\le0$, $x=6$, which is impossible and for $x\ge0$, $x+|7-2x|-(7-2x)=6$.

You still  have to distinguish $2x\le7$, giving $x=6$, which is impossible, and for $2x\ge7$, $x-14+4x=6$ or $$\color{green}{x=4,y=-1}.$$

Not much simpler.